# I want to Read Multiple excel sheets in one file without using OLEDB in C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2008, import-from-excel

Im reading an Excel document from C# Windows Form.. There are 25 worksheets in Excel Workbook.. i can read 1st worksheet successfully.. But when i change it to worksheet 2.. it won't working at all.. Im not using OLEDB..

I want to read 100 Row in every sheet.. following is my code...

```
`       dt.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(double));
        dt.Columns.Add("ChequeNo", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("month", typeof(int));


        int AmountRow = 100;
        int ChequeNoRow = 101;
        int Column = 3;

        xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets[2];\\This place is the changing worksheets

        range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;

        double chequeAmount;
        double chequeNo;

        for (int i = Column; i < 15; i++)
        {
            chequeAmount = (double)(range.Cells[AmountRow, i] as Excel.Range).Value2;
            chequeNo = (double)(range.Cells[ChequeNoRow, i] as Excel.Range).Value2;

            if (chequeNo != 0.0)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(Convert.ToDouble(chequeAmount), Convert.ToInt32(chequeNo), i);
            }
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, null, null);
        xlApp.Quit();

        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
        releaseObject(xlApp);`
```

releaseObject methods are not here.. those working perfectly...

```
 `xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets[1];`
```

This is how i change my worksheets.. The following line gives an exception..[Null point Exception]

`chequeAmount = (double)(range.Cells[AmountRow, i] as Excel.Range).Value2;`

Hope you'll know answers..

Comment: Use [Linq-To-Excel](http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/) instead. It's absolutely awesome.

Comment: There were some exceptions bro... we adviced not to use any LinQ at all.. thats the problem.. thankz for comment..

Comment: That seems to be an odd requirement. Why can't you use LINQ?

Comment: try oXL.Workbooks["1"].Activate();
oSheet = (Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

Comment: side note: You might be better off with performance if you fetch the required range once using one .Value2 call which will return an object[,] 2d array object. The VSTO calls inside for loop can be avoided then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

`xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets[2];`

The `Sheets` property can include non-worksheet sheets, which could be the issue in your scenario.